# Lotus Notes Agents - Auto Reply only to internet email

Tags: lotus-notes

I've created a simple agent for one of our mail-in db. This agents sends a reply to the sender.

However, I want to put a condition where in internal emails(internal email example - suman selvaraj/ABC/XYZ) should be excluded in the above agent and only internet emails(suman.selvaraj@xyz.com) should be replied to.

Can you please advise.

Thank You!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the @ValidateInternetAddress function.  Documentation can be found [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_VALIDATEINTERNETADDRESS_5866_OVER.html).

Comment: Unable to click the link, Richard.

Comment: That's because I clicked the code icon instead of the link icon!  Duh!  Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Lookup @Contains in the help file.